# Redirecting when user is authenticated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to build a role based access control React app.

My vision was that when the `App` mounts, it checks if user token exists. If it does, it runs `checkAuthToken()` and sets the state accordingly.

Where I am struggling is: redirection doesn't work as I expect it to.

Here is my code:

in `App.js`

```
function App() {
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector(state => {
    return state.userState;
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/'>
          {!isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to='/login'/>
          ) : (
            <Redirect to={`/${user.role}`} />
          )}
        </Route>

        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => {
            return <Login />;
          }}
        />


        <Route
          path="/admin"
          render={() => {
            return <AdminDashboard user={user} />;
          }}
        />
        <Route
          path="/staff"
          render={() => {
            return <OrderMenu user={user} />;
          }}
        />
        <Route component={ErrorPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My understanding is React rerenders when state or props change. When I get the updated state from Redux, the app component should rerender and thus go through the `isAuthenticated` check and redirect accordingly, but i'm being proven wrong.

Currently, if there's no token, it redirects to `Login route`. After user logs in, token is set in localStorage. So to test it out, I close and open a new tab, try to go to path `/` expecting it to redirect me to `/[admin|staff]` route since `checkAuthToken` would successfully set the state but redirect doesn't work and just lands on `/login`. However, I could access `/[admin|staff]` if I type in manually.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to dispatch checkauthtoken action?

Comment: the dispatch function happens inside `checkAuthToken`